# How do I build Breadcrumbs for a certain node?

Tags: 8, routes, uri, breadcrumbs, symfony-services

In a node preprocess hook I am getting breadcrumbs for the currently viewed node by doing the following:

```
$vars['breadcrumb'] = Drupal::service('breadcrumb')
    ->build(Drupal::routeMatch())->toRenderable();
```

This works fine as it uses `Drupal::routeMatch()` to get the matched route for the current request.

But I also want to get the breadcrumb for each node in a listing of several nodes. In this case I cannot use `Drupal::routeMatch()` since I want to get the breadcrumb for each node in the listing, not the current page. The problem is I cannot find a way of getting a RouteMatchInterface object (needed by the BreadcrumbBuilder) from a node object. I can get the url containing route information via `$node->urlInfo()`but there seems to be no way of getting from there to a route match either.

How can this be done?

**Edit:**

I found a way to get the route match for a certain node. Not sure if it's the ideal way but it gets the job done:

```
$routeName = $node->urlInfo()->getRouteName();
$routeParameters = $node->urlInfo()->getRouteParameters();
$route = Drupal::service('router.route_provider')->getRouteByName($routeName);
$routeMatch = new RouteMatch($routeName, $route, $routeParameters);
```

However passing the `$routeMatch` into `PathBasedBredcrumbBuilder::create` does not generate bredcrumbs for that route!

On closer inspection it seems that the built-in `PathBasedBreadCrumbBuilder` class completely ignores the passed in `$routeMatch` parameter and instead builds the breadcrumbs using the path of the current page, fetched using the injected RequestContext object. I think I would need to swap out this service with my own implementation which uses the passed in parameters somehow. To be continued...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually solved it by creating my own subclass of the PathBasedBredcrumbBuilder from core. This class unlike core's version actually uses the passed in route_match and returns breadcrumbs based on that which makes it possible to get breadcrumbs for a certain node (or any other given route).

I still need to calculate the route match from the current node to pass to the build method (as shown in the question). It feels a bit awkward since the route_match is converted back into a url object in the build method but  it works and it is the cleanest solution i've come up with so far.

Below is the subclass:

```
namespace Drupal\contextual_breadcrumbs;

use Drupal\system\PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RequestContext;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

class ContextualPathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder extends PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder {

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {

      /// Set request context from passed in $route_match
      $url = Url::fromRouteMatch($route_match);
      if ($request = $this->getRequestForPath($url->toString(), [])) {
        $context = new RequestContext();
        $context->fromRequest($request);
        $this->context = $context;
      } 

      // Build breadcrumbs using new context ($route_match is unused)
      return parent::build($route_match);
    }

}
```

Comment: I confirm both solutions from reekris works perfectly, you should use https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services to override the default PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder

Comment: Moreover, if you are using the MenuBasedBreadcrumbBuilder, it may generate incorrect breadcrumbs too. If so, take a look at : https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb/issues/3026188#comment-12928194

Answer (score 0):

It seems you could use the service_collector to just add your custom ContextualPathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder.

For that just add in your modules services.yml:

```
  my_custom_module.breadcrumb:
    class: Drupal\ my_custom_module.breadcrumb\CustomBreadcrumbBuilder
    arguments: ['@router.request_context', '@access_manager', '@router', '@path_processor_manager', '@config.factory',  '@title_resolver', '@current_user', '@path.current', '@path.matcher']
    tags:
      - { name: breadcrumb_builder, priority: 1002 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but I had to amend the ContextualPathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder to following for it to work, it was complaining about missing node parameter before:

```
class ContextualPathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder extends PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {

    $url = Url::fromRoute($route_match->getRouteName(), $route_match->getParameters()->all());

    if ($request = $this->getRequestForPath($url->toString(), [])) {
      $context = new RequestContext();
      $context->fromRequest($request);
      $this->context = $context;
    }

    // Build breadcrumbs using new context ($route_match is unused)
    return parent::build($route_match);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 9 you don't need to extend anything. Working code here:

```
$routeName = $entity->toUrl()->getRouteName();
$routeParameters = $entity->toUrl()->getRouteParameters();
$route = Drupal::service('router.route_provider')->getRouteByName($routeName);
$routeMatch = new Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch($routeName, $route, $routeParameters, $routeParameters);
$build['search_breadcrumb'] = Drupal::service('breadcrumb')->build($routeMatch)->toRenderable();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Build Breadcrumbs for a certain node in Drupal-9.**

*Code is running with Drupal-9:*

```
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);

$routeName = $entity->toUrl()->getRouteName();
$routeParameters = $entity->toUrl()->getRouteParameters();
$route = \Drupal::service('router.route_provider')->getRouteByName($routeName);
$routeMatch = new \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch($routeName, $route, $routeParameters, $routeParameters);
$breadcrumb = \Drupal::service('breadcrumb')->build($routeMatch)->toRenderable();

dump($breadcrumb)
```

Output:

```
^ array:3 [▼
"#cache" => array:3 [▼
    "contexts" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "route"
      1 => "url.path"
      2 => "languages"
    ]
    "tags" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "config:easy_breadcrumb.settings"
    ]
    "max-age" => -1
  ]
  "#theme" => "breadcrumb"
  "#links" => array:1 [▼
    0 => Drupal\Core\Link {#4369 ▼
      #linkGenerator: null
      #text: "Home"
      #url: Drupal\Core\Url {#4752 ▼
        #urlGenerator: null
        #urlAssembler: null
        #accessManager: null
        #routeName: "<front>"
        #routeParameters: []
        #options: []
        #external: false
        #unrouted: false
        #uri: null
        #internalPath: null
        #_serviceIds: []
        #_entityStorages: []
      }
    }
  ]
]
```