# Fetching breadcrumb in search result list

Tags: 8, nodes, search, breadcrumbs

I am trying to get the breadcrumb, for nodes in search result listing.

I came to know that breadcrumb by default fetches the current node context, so I followed the suggestion from here - [How do I build Breadcrumbs for a certain node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191548/how-do-i-build-breadcrumbs-for-a-certain-node) to override the PathBasedBreadCrumbBuilder and providing the context to it by creating the RouteMatcher. But still, I am not able to get the desired result and it still shows the current page breadcrumb, rather then breadcrumb for each node in result.

The code for `CustomPathBasedBreadCrumBuilder` is the following.

```php
namespace Drupal\custom_module;

use Drupal\system\PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RequestContext;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Class to implement custom Breadcrumb builder, based on passed route.
 */
class CustomPathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder extends PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  
    // Set request context from passed in $route_match.
    // I was not getting the URL from RouteMatch object like below.

    // $url = Url::fromRouteMatch($route_match);
    
    // @todo Generate the actual URL from RouteMatch.
    // So I tried with passing a fixed node id just to check if it overrides.
    // TESTING - passing the nid to generate the breadcrumb for URL context.

    $options = ['absolute' => FALSE];
    $url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 81], $options)->toString();

    if ($request = $this->getRequestForPath($url, [])) {
      $context = new RequestContext();
      $context->fromRequest($request);
      $this->context = $context;
    }
    // Build breadcrumbs using new context ($route_match is unused)
    return parent::build($route_match);
  }

}
```

I created a service for it.

```yaml
custom_module.breadcrumb:
    class: Drupal\custom_module\CustomPathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder
    arguments: ['@router.request_context', '@access_manager', '@router', '@path_processor_manager', '@config.factory',  '@title_resolver', '@current_user', '@path.current', '@path.matcher']
    tags:
      - { name: breadcrumb_builder, priority: 1002 }
```

In the theme, I called service in `hook_preprocess_node()`.

```php
function custom_module_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $view_mode = $variables['elements']['#view_mode'];
  $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
  // Prepare search result content.
  if ($view_mode == 'search_result') {
    $routeName = $node->toUrl()->getRouteName();
    $route = \Drupal::service('router.route_provider')->getRouteByName($routeName);
    $routeParameters = $node->toUrl()->getRouteParameters();
    // Prepare the RouteMatch parameter for overridng breadcrumb.
    $routeMatch = new RouteMatch($routeName, $route, $routeParameters, $routeParameters);
    $variables['search_breadcrumb'] = Drupal::service('custom_module.breadcrumb')->build($routeMatch)->toRenderable();
  }
```

I am able to override context based on the URL which I am passing to the request,  but it's still returning the breadcrumb for the current node on which result are rendering, rather than for each node in list.

I am not sure what changed or where I am doing it wrong.

#### References

- [How do I build Breadcrumbs for a certain node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191548/how-do-i-build-breadcrumbs-for-a-certain-node)
- https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2017-06-23/how-to-create-currentroutematch